# Master page inherits tag question

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Going through the microsoft authentication tutorial listed [here](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Security/tutorial-02-cs.aspx) they have you create a master page.  Upon generation by Visual Studio the first list in the file looks like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="FormsAuthentication.Site" %>
```

The project is called FormAuthentication and the master page is named Site.Master.  When running the project I get the error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0426: The type name 'Site' does not exist in the type 'System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication'
```

and the line referenced looks like this, in an auto-generated file

```
Line 133:        [TemplateContainer(typeof(FormsAuthentication.Site))]
```

Removing the "Inherits='FormsAuthentication.Site' " portion of that initial tag resolves the issue but I'm trying to understand what is happening here.  What is actually going on here?

Comment: +1 for giving a little background on the problem, and asking a specific question. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Name of your project (and maybe namespaces) conflicts with ASP.NET form authentification class name: `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication`. I think you are missing namespace name or reference.

Comment: So this is just an unfortunate naming choice on my part?  /sheepish

Comment: Both yes and no - if you've choosen another name the error would not happen. But I think you can try modifying Iherits attribute to set your master pages namespace. If you don't have one you can add it to the code and attribute.

Comment: Here is info on namespaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973231.aspx#assenamesp_topic5

Answer (score 1):

If you could rename, or add another level of namespace around FormsAUthentication so that it would be like: Custom.FormsAuthentication.Site, that would alleviate the problem.